# Difference between dates of format dd/mm/yy in Jquery

Tags: jquery, date

How to find difference(number of days) between two dates in Jquery, which is of the format **dd/mm/yy** ?

This is what I have tried:

```
var start = $('#start').val(); //30/04/2014
var end = $('#end').val();     // 15/05/2014
var diff = new Date(end - start);
var days = diff/1000/60/60/24
```

;

Comment: Why -1? I couldn't find a solution anywhere for this.

Comment: You can't have been looking very hard - http://bit.ly/1ivIXRM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var startDate= $("#start").datepicker('getDate');
var endDate= $("#end").datepicker('getDate');

var diffInDays = Math.round((startDate.getTime()- endDate.getTime())
                             /1000*60*60*24);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked :)
+1 for now. Will accept the answer later.

Answer (score 1):

A little change on the above code:

```html
var startDate= $("#start").datepicker('getDate');
var endDate= $("#end").datepicker('getDate');

var diffInDays = Math.round((endDate.getTime()- startDate.getTime())/(1000*60*60*24));
```